# Keeping list of attached files of a page with TempData without any conflict with another instanse of the page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

**Hello Friends...**

I have a mvc project and a form with a attachment box (such as yahoo mail compose)

for example "create_request.cshtml"

---

**I want:**

each user fill the fields and upload his/her files (i post each file by Ajax when the user select any one)  and after submit the form, if the page has error (checked server side), user see the uploaded files in the response page (response form with highlighted errors)...

---

**I implemented the above scenario very nice:**

(Ajax+ Tempdata+ save the files server side befor submit  + Thumbs of uploaded files befor submit the form)

in my controller:

```
 public void KeepTempData(string name, string value)
    {
        TempData[name] = value;
    }
```

in my view i send each file name to the server after i upload it by another ajax codes:

```
ajaxPostData(KeepTempData, "Attachments", $('#Attachments').val());
```

---

**But i have a problem:**

Because i used **TempData** for keeping list of uploaded filenames, if the user attach a file in the current page then opens a new Tab in her/his browser and goes to the  "create_request" page address. He/She see an empty form with a attached file...

**My Solution:**

Maybe I can solve this problem with a unique key for each page (each form) and keeping it in a session variable and a hidden field for each page request>> using: *"Anti Forgery Token with a Salt"* or *"DateTime.Now"*

**I found [This post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?95016-Using-Session-Model-Attributes-With-Multiple-Browser-Tabs-Patch) on the web. its problem is like as my problem. and its solution is like as my solution.**

---

**What is appropriate solutions in MVC for this problem???**

**What is your recommendation for using TempData's (or Session's) without any conflict when user have different requests of a pages in some tabs of a browser (like firfox)???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem by:

- Get a key from querystring
- If the key is empty

  - I generate a new and unique key in the action of controller
  - Redirect the page to a new url with the key (as a querystring key-value)
- Else

  - Adding the key to the ViewBag (for set a hidden field in view)
  - Save the key in a session variable.

.

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(string attkey)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attkey))
     {
         attkey = generatNewNameForSession('key'); // for examle: kye_jhtyujbvkjadsgfvn
         Response.Redirect("myControle/Create, attkey="+attkey), true);
        }
        ViewBag.AttachmentsKey = attkey;
        if (Session[attkey] == null)
            KeepData(attkey, "");
        .
        .
        .
```

Now each instance of my page has a Identification and now i can decide shown or not shown the previously attached files.

Answer (score 0):

TempData has very short lifespan. You should use Session instead of TempData.

Infact session object is the backing storage behind TempData. But the data stored in TempData is available to the current request and Subsequent request.

Comment: i fill my TempData on this events (base on attachment field >> it is a hidden field):
-On user select a file and upload it
-On refresh the page
-On get response page (after submit)

my problem :
if the user attach a file in the current page then opens a new Tab in her/his browser and goes to the "create_request" page address. He/She see an empty form with a attached file...